# how can i create a helper type function in my redux module to return a filtered set of readonly data from state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Using redux, I am trying to write a "helper function" in my redux module which returns filtered data from state based on what index i pass into it. This data is used to build out a form of inputs based on whether `auth: true` or `budt: true`. The form basically would iterate over all totypes for that level and conditionally show/hide the auth or budt inputs.

Given the state...

```
  totypesmap: [
    {
      level:1,
      totypes:[
        {ttno:1, ttcode:'', ttdesc:'regular', auth:true, budt:false},
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I have a function exported in my module that expects an `index` argument and returns its appropriate `totypesmap[index]` from state. However in order to get to state from within it i have to use `getState()` which expects a Promise to be resolved with its data I am assuming.

Should i be accomplishing this some other way?

```
export const MyTOTypes = (level) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const state = getState()
    // return state.masterdata.totypesmap[level].totypes
  }
}
```

In my container or component I simply `import { MyTOTypes } from 'redux/modules/masterdata'` and then call it whenever i need to know the TO Types assigned to my "level" `MyTOTypes(0)`

Answer (score 1):

If the data is constant, don't put it in the redux store.  Just put it in a module and expose your helper methods to retrieve the data.

```
const totypesmap = [ ... ];
export function MyToTypes(level) { return totypesmap[level].totypes; }
```

If you really want it in the Redux store, then have your method take `state` as the first argument.  Your React components will be calling this method from within their `mapStateToProps` method and will have the store state available:

```
export function MyToTypes(state, level) { return state.totypesmap[level].totypes; }
```

Comment: the master data isnt really considered constant, as its pulled from the backend on componentDidMount and pushed into the store. I need to basically write some function that filters the totypesmap to just the level i want. I could write a function in each container but thats repetitive. The idea is to be able to use this function anywhere and not need to pass in state.

Comment: then have your helper function take `state` as the first argument and have your components call the helper function from within the `mapStateToProps` method of `connect`.